# Is it possible to fix the 'help-curwin' command / function from vim help tips?

Tags: vim

I do not understand vim script very well, just enough to tinker with my vimrc. So I am looking for someone's help to understand what can be done here.

I use this `HelpCurWin` command from the vim help page 'tips.txt', tag 'help-curwin'. The command is designed to open a given help page in the current window instead of opening a new split. This part works fine. Here is the code:

```
" Command to open help page in current window.
command -bar -nargs=? -complete=help HelpCurwin
      \ execute s:HelpCurwin(<q-args>)
let s:did_open_help = v:false
function s:HelpCurwin(subject) abort
  let mods = 'silent noautocmd keepalt'
  if !s:did_open_help
    execute mods .. ' help'
    execute mods .. ' helpclose'
    let s:did_open_help = v:true
  endif
  if !getcompletion(a:subject, 'help')->empty()
    execute mods .. ' edit ' .. &helpfile
  endif
  return 'help ' .. a:subject
endfunction
```

Here is a slightly diferent version from the nvim documentation (I tried both):

```
" Command to open help page in current window.
command -bar -nargs=? -complete=help HelpCurwin
      \ execute s:HelpCurwin(<q-args>)
let s:did_open_help = v:false
function s:HelpCurwin(subject) abort
  let mods = 'silent noautocmd keepalt'
  if !s:did_open_help
    execute mods .. ' help'
    execute mods .. ' helpclose'
    let s:did_open_help = v:true
  endif
  " Fix from nvim documentation.
  if !empty(getcompletion(a:subject, 'help'))
    execute mods .. ' edit ' .. &helpfile
  endif
  return 'help ' .. a:subject
endfunction
```

As I was saying the main goal of opening the help page in the current window is achieved, but, there are 3 side effects I noticed:

1. When I open a specific help page, the default 'help.txt' page will automatically be added to the buffer list,
2. The 'help.txt' page will not be added to the list as an "unlisted" buffer which clutters the tabline, and the buffer list,
3. Even if I issue `:HelpCurwin` with no page specified, the 'help.txt' page will be listed as a regular buffer and not get syntax highlighting (even though the filetype is correctly set).

Those are not critical issues, but it is bugging me, and I would be grateful if anyone could help me fix it, or, if impossible, explain me why.

EDIT: I forgot to specify that I am personally using this function mostly from vertically split windows, so I am looking to improve it primarily for that use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with that is a bit less hacky (IMO) than the recommended solution and doesn't suffer from the problem of polluting the buffer list.

```
" Open help in the current window with :Help
command! -bar -nargs=? -complete=help Help call s:HelpHere(<q-args>)

function! s:HelpHere(subject) abort

  " remember the state of the windows
  let l:window_id = win_getid()
  let l:window_width = winwidth(0)
  let l:num_windows = winnr('$')
  
  " open the help window
  execute 'help ' .. a:subject

  " close the original window if a new help window was opened, and
  " if it should have opened immediately above the original window
  if l:num_windows < winnr('$') && (l:num_windows == 1 || l:window_width >= 80)
    call win_execute(l:window_id, 'close')
  endif

endfunction
```

The new `:Help` command is implemented by the function `s:HelpHere`. This function just passes its argument to the standard `:help` command, then closes the original window if `:help` created a new window.

Most of the time, this simulates opening the help window in the window that `:Help` was invoked from.

However, if the standard `:help` command is invoked from a narrow window, then it will create a new window on top of potentially several vertically split windows, so closing the original window doesn't simulate what we want. In this case, my `:Help` command doesn't close the original window and just preserves the default behavior of `:help`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tested your function, and it does work fine for horizontally split windows. I rarely use those, so I did not even know that vim help was opening an h-split on top of already horizontally split windows. Anyway, your solution in that use case is very clean, and the buffer list stays uncluttered. However, I almost exclusively use v-split and this is the actual use case I was looking for. This is my fault, I did not specify it in my post which I will edit. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: I almost exclusively use v-splits too and it should work in that context as well, *unless* the v-splits are narrower than 80 characters. If the v-split that `:Help` was invoked from is less than 80 characters, than my solution falls back on the default `:help` behavior.

Comment: Is `:help` itself opening a v-split? If so, I don't think that is the default behavior, so you might have some other setting that is conflicting with this.

Comment: I just had a look at the code, and yes, the 80 char limit is pretty easy to spot, thanks for clarifying for me. I think you are right, my typical setup on my laptop with two vertical windows and line numbers give me right below 80 char actually (even 79 if I remember correctly). I am going to try to tweak it see if I can make it work. (Fyi, :help does open a horizontal window by default with my setup, I just heavily use :vert help)

Comment: So yes, my typical v-splits are 74 char wide. I tried changing the 80 figure in your function down to 70 just to try out, and it still closes the original v-split I invoked :Help from, and falls back to a normal :help behavior. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately the approach just doesn't work if the v-split is less than 80 characters wide. The problem is that `:help` behaves differently (see `:help help`) in that scenario, which is why I set that as the minimum.

It's really annoying that vim doesn't give you any control at all over where the help window opens...

Comment: I agree with you, vim help is such a great tool, it is a shame to have to battle with window placement but still, I use it too much to complain :)  So I simply changed my font size to try out your command, and it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the relevant help page, I am re-discovering help behavior with wider windows. I also understand now why your solution (using the original :help function) cannot make it work in my particular configuration. Thanks again for your help.